# Is it bad form to provide only a move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-constructor, move-semantics

I would like to return a noncopyable object of type `Foo` from a function. This is basically a helper object which the caller will use to perform a set of actions, with a destructor to perform some cleanup after the actions are complete.

Before the advent of [rvalue references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Rvalue_reference_and_move_semantics), I would have returned a `shared_ptr<Foo>` or something similar. With rvalue references, another option would be to make the constructor and copy constructor private, and have the only public constructor be a move constructor. `Foo` would look something like this:

```
class Foo : boost::noncopyable
{
private:
    Foo( /* whatever the real ctor needs */ );

public:
    Foo( Foo && src );

    // ... interesting stuff ...
};

Foo a( SomethingThatReturnsFoo() ); // allowed
Foo b;      // error, no public default constructor
Foo c( a ); // error, noncopyable
Foo d = a;  // error, noncopyable
```

My question is whether it would be bad form to do this, or whether it looks reasonable. I can't think of any reason why this would cause issues or be difficult to read, but I'm still somewhat of a newbie when it comes to rvalue references, so there might be considerations I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Minor remark: if you provide a `Move Constructor`, people will probably expect a `Move Assignment Operator` as well. Do you plan on providing it, or do you want an immutable class ?

Comment: In this particular case it's intended to be immutable, so I don't want assignment, but that's a good point in general.

Comment: btw, with the recent changes in the compiler-generated copy/move operations department, you actually don't need to derive from boost::noncopyable anymore. Declaring a move constructor will already prevent the compiler from generating any other copy/move operations, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3203.htm

Comment: Isn't it better to be safe, and better form as well, to `delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment operator explicitly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't bad form at all- consider objects like mutexes or scoped objects like unique_ptr. Unique_ptr is movable but not copyable and it's part of the STL.

Comment: I'd even add that it is *very good form*. I sincerely think that copyable objects should be the *exception*, not the rule. The more I use C++0x, the more I am confident in this thinking.